# dependency injection Ioc with interface segregation

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am using two database oracle and sql server. I am making system generic using dependency injection.Code is following

```
public interface IDatabases
{
   string GetEmployeeFullName();

}
public class OracleDB:IDatabases
{
  public string GetEmployeeFullName()
 {
   return "Name oracle";
  }
}
public class SqlServerDB : IDatabases
{
  public string GetEmployeeFullName()
  {
   return "Name sql server";
   }
}
public class RegistrationStaff 
{
  private IDatabases objDatabase;
  public RegistrationStaff(IDatabases vobjDataBase)
  {
         this.objDatabase = vobjDataBase;            
  }
}
```

I need another function GetEmployeeId in sql server class which will return employee id which is available in sql server database.I do not want this function implementation in oracle.How can I use interface segregation with dependency injection and implement in RegistrationStaff class .

```
public interface IsqlServer:IDatabases
    {
void GetEmployeeId();
}
```

I want only dependency injection using constructor

Comment: instead of negative mark.Share solution

Comment: How does the client (`RegistrationStaff`) decide if/when to invoke the `GetEmployeeId` method? If you forget about interfaces/classes/DI for a moment, can you describe the logic in a procedural way? Like in a flow chart for example.

Comment: I want decoupling that's why i am using inversion of control with dependency injection and also Ioc container.I am not getting your question.What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem. Designing interfaces should begin with the client as per the Dependency Inversion Principle. It's not clear in the question what the client (`RegistrationStaff`) is trying to do.

Comment: RegistrationStaff is bussiness access layer.I am using asp.net web forms

Comment: Yes. But what does it need to do? How does it need to interact with the database (forgetting for a moment about classes/interfaces/DI)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are already on the right way. Make a new interface for the segregation, add the new method and let the SQL server class inherit from it. So after all you have to cast the database object in the Registration class to call the method. But I can't see a way without casting if you don't put the method at top level.

```
        public interface IDatabases
        {
            string GetEmployeeFullName();
        }

        public interface ISQLDatabase : IDatabases
        {
            int GetEmployeeId();
        }

        public class OracleDB : IDatabases
        {
            public string GetEmployeeFullName()
            {
                return "Name oracle";
            }
        }

        public class SqlServerDB : ISQLDatabase
        {
            public string GetEmployeeFullName()
            {
                return "Name sql server";
            }

            public int GetEmployeeId()
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public class RegistrationStaff
        {
            private IDatabases objDatabase;

            public RegistrationStaff(IDatabases vobjDataBase)
            {
                this.objDatabase = vobjDataBase;

                if (this.objDatabase is ISQLDatabase)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(((ISQLDatabase)this.objDatabase).GetEmployeeId());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am confuse how to put dependency of sql server
 IDatabases  objDb = new ?
what i put like this
IDatabases  objDb = new SqlServerDB();

Comment: RegistrationStaff regStaff = new RegistrationStaff(objDb);

Comment: Yes, you can simply do something like this: `var regStuff = new RegistrationStaff(new SqlServerDB());` or `var regStuff2 = new RegistrationStaff(new OracleDB());`